# Apache Directive LocationMatch - Secure Admin Access

Tags: magento-1.7, apache

I am trying to restrict Admin Access to my Magento site, to allow a specific ip address, only. I found tutorials that mention the following:

Apache directive LocationMatch:

```
<code>
<LocationMatch "admin">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 10.10.10.0/24
</LocationMatch>
</code>
```

What is 'Apache Directive LocationMatch' and where do I add this? Totally clueless. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Apache directive LocationMatch matches a requested url with the mentioned one in the condition.
Please refer this link for more information about "*Apache directive LocationMatch:*"
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch

You should add the code to your .htaccess file which will be in the Magento root folder.

```
<code>
<LocationMatch "admin">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from 10.10.10.0/24
</LocationMatch>
</code>
```

If you are using custom admin path then replace admin with the custom path in
`<LocationMatch "admin">`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize this just went into the .htaccess file - I thought it was way more complex than that. Much appreciated again, for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I added this to my .htaccess file in my root directory, changed the ip address to be mine and changed "admin" to be my custom admin path, but it gives me a '500 Internal Server Error'. Any ideas?

Comment: Enter your public ip address after Allow from

Comment: Yep, I did that. Just to confirm the frontend (not just admin) is giving the Internal Server Error.

Comment: It should work I have tested on my system.

Comment: That's odd. Just to confirm this is going in the .htaccess file in the root of my Magento folders?

Comment: Maybe it's to do with how my files are setup? To get to admin I don't just go to '/admin', I have to go to '/index.php/admin/dashboard/index' ?